# jqGrid sends wrong id on cell edit

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

I have a grid that gets 2 rows from a handler, I try to identify the key column, here I renamed it from id to xqz and rr45.  When I edit a Cell, my handdler is getting an id of 1 which appears to be the rownumber and not the actual id.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jQgrid - ASPX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://asp2d:1138/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://asp2d:1138/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://asp2d:1138/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://asp2d:1138/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "/capplanning/SitePages/jsonhandler.aspx?wherefrom=Category One",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",

                colNames: ["xyz", "category_type", "category_value"],
                colModel: [{
                    name: "rr45",
                    sortable: true,
                    key: true,
                    editable: true,
                    hidden: true,
                    edithidden: false
                }, {
                    name: "category_type",
                    sortable: true,
                    editable: false
                }, {
                    name: "category_value",
                    sortable: true,
                    editable: true
                }],
                pager: "#pager",
                caption: "Category One",
                loadonce: "true",
                height: "100%",
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: "remote",
                cellurl: "/capplanning/SitePages/jsonhandler.aspx?editedgrid=editcategory1",
                autowidth: true,
                rowNum: 9999,
                gridview: true,
                multiselect: false
                    /*rowList:[10,15,20]*/
            });
            $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                stringResult: true,
                searchOnEnter: false
            });
            $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                edit: false,
                add: true,
                del: true
            });

            $("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
                caption: '',
                title: 'Show/Hide Filters',
                buttonicon: 'ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e',
                onClickButton: function() {
                    this.toggleToolbar();
                    if ($.isFunction(this.p._complete)) {
                        if ($('.ui-search-toolbar', this.grid.hDiv).is(':visible')) {
                            $('.ui-search-toolbar', this.grid.fhDiv).show();
                        } else {
                            $('.ui-search-toolbar', this.grid.fhDiv).hide();
                        }
                        this.p._complete.call(this);
                        fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#list")[0].toggleToolbar();

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="list">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "id": "2",
        "cell": ["2", "CategoryOne", "Maintenancedd"]
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "cell": ["3", "CategoryOne", "Maintenance"]
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "cell": ["4", "CategoryOne", "New Growth"]
    }]
}
```

In my edit handler it comes up with

```
Key = category_value  Value = Maintenance
Key = id  Value = **1**
Key = oper  Value = edit
```

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** You input data contains `id` property separately. In the case I would recommend you to try to **remove `key: true`** from `"rr45"`. The version 4.7 for example had the corresponding bug.

Comment: nothing seems to work, no combination of removing key: true or renaming the columns.  I think I am using 4.8.2.  Sorry I am not too sure how to check the version.  The directory with jqgrid is named Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.8.2.

Comment: Oleg if you know a way for me to pass another column on cell edit as well as id I could put my own id column in, there doesnt seem to be a good answer to this issue anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a definite bug here, jqGrid loads row id's as ordinals not the field that is bound through the primary key column, to fix this I have implemented what can only be described as a dirty hack!

first, create a client side event handler when you bind your grid model:

```
ClientSideEvents cev = new ClientSideEvents() {
    GridInitialized = "loadComplete"
};
```

"loadComplete" is a javascript function in my main .js stack:

```
function loadComplete() {
    $('tr.jqgrow[role="row"]').each(function (i, e) {
        var Id = $(e).children().first().attr("title");
        $(e).attr("id", Id);
    });
};
```

This basically, allows the grid to complete its render, then rips through finding the fist column (assuming this is the ID field, in my case, it always is) and sets the row "id" attribute to the value of the "title" attribute in the first child (which does get the correct value) thereby setting the row ID to the correct value

What a pile of dog poo this grid really is.. :(